# java forkJoin Pool and does it make the thread a daemon one implicitly?

Tags: java, iteration, forkjoinpool

Is it efficient to iterate a List or Map.values() using forkJoinPool thread? or the simple Thread will satisfy the efficiency?
When is it preferred to use forkJoinPool?
and does it make the thread a daemon thread implicitly?

Comment: Not too sure what you are trying to say, perhaps add some sample codes to illustrate? Are you talking about something similar to what parallel stream API has done?

Comment: It's clear I think, I have a class which extends RecursiveTask<> and has a compute method overridden in which I iterate a map or maybe an array and find a specific element and my question is whether it is efficient to fork the array into sub arrays and search it or not

Comment: The short answer is yes. I think the *real* question is the difference between using a `ForkJoinPool` and simple `Thread` or `ExecutorService`. Using `ForkJoinPool` and `ForkJoinTask` is only really useful if you actually managed to do meaningful forks. If you are going to do something for each element of the `List` where the action cannot be further split, then there isn't much difference using `ForkJoinPool` and `ExecutorService` (or spawn a new thread for each element).

Comment: and my second question about deamon thread??

Comment: Yes, they are, by default, daemon threads. The only way to make them non-daemon threads is to provide a custom `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` in the constructor, and manually calling `setDaemon(false)` when overridding `newThread()` method.

Comment: Well thanks for this nice explanation